# Strapi relations, returning other fields except id

Tags: javascript, strapi

I want to make some simple Rest API backend with Strapi.io and I have no experience in backend, ORM, relations and etc., so I have troubles. Idea is make structure of dishes with ingridients and calculation. I have table ingridients, table compositions that have two fields ingridient id and amount of it. Also I have dishes table which belongs to many compositions. Right now I have this situation when I call api/dishes/3 and it's not suitable for me:

```
{
"id": 3,
"name": "DishName",
"compositions": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "amount": 100,
        "ingridient": 2,
        "dish": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "amount": 100,
        "ingridient": 1,
        "dish": 3
    }
]}
```

I want API which work like this:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "DishName",
    "compositions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "amount": 100,
            "ingridient": { id: 1, name: "IngridientName" },
            "dish": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "amount": 100,
            "ingridient": { id: 2, name: "SecondIngridientName" },
            "dish": 3
        }
    ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

please see this answer by @lauriejim from the Strapi team: https://spectrum.chat/strapi/general/group-doesnt-appear-on-findall-with-relations~c0bcc957-3170-4e80-96de-ee3e7625b5bf?m=MTU3NTU1MjQxNTc3NA==

What you are looking to do is called "Custom Populate" you will need to override the controller, the link I provided should answer your question.